# Android: Google Developer Console shows supported devices 0?

Tags: android, xml, google-play, android-manifest

Shows up as supported devices 0 in developer console.
I tried getting rid of screenOrientation="portrait".
Could it be the .MainActivity?

What I have tried:

Changing permissions.
Changing MainActivity.java
Altering activity_main and
         fragment_main.

Removed all permissions & features required

What I have read:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fewquery.orb"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.flash"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.autofocus"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's

```
android.hardware.camera.autofocus

android.hardware.camera.flash
```

not

```
android.hardware.autofocus

android.hardware.flash
```

See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features)